# Why $e^{-\ln x} = e^{\ln x^{-1}}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $\begin{array}{cl}
> =&e^{-\ln x}\\
> =&e^{\ln x^{-1}}\\
> =&x^{-1}\\
> =&\dfrac1x
> \end{array}$

How is switching from $e^{-\ln x}$ to $e^{\ln x^{-1}}$ possible?

Comment: $n \ln x \equiv \ln (x^n)$

Comment: Would $e^{-\ln(x)}=\dfrac{1}{e^{\ln(x)}}=\dfrac{1}{x}$ be clearer (although it wouldn't answer your question)?  To me $\ln x^{-1}$ is pointless avoidance of parentheses unless used among people who already have enough fluency to guess from context what is intended.  $-\ln(x)=\ln(x^{-1})$.  Especially with the nested exponents it's potentially ambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

$$
0=\ln1=\ln\left(x\times\frac1x\right)=\ln x+\ln\frac1x.
$$
It follows that 
$$
\ln\frac1x=-\ln x.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Definition of $\ln x$:

$$\ln x := \int_1^x \dfrac{\mathrm dt}t$$

Then:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\ln x + \ln x^{-1}
&=& \displaystyle \int_1^x \dfrac{\mathrm dt}t + \int_1^{x^{-1}} \dfrac{\mathrm dt}t \\
&=& \displaystyle \int_1^x \dfrac{\mathrm dt}t + \int_x^1 \dfrac{\mathrm d(xt)}{xt} \\
&=& \displaystyle \int_1^x \dfrac{\mathrm dt}t + \int_x^1 \dfrac{x\ \mathrm dt}{xt} \\
&=& \displaystyle \int_1^x \dfrac{\mathrm dt}t + \int_x^1 \dfrac{\mathrm dt}t \\
&=& \displaystyle \int_1^x \dfrac{\mathrm dt}t - \int_1^x \dfrac{\mathrm dt}t \\
&=& 0
\end{array}$$

Subtract $\ln x $ from both sides to get:

$$\ln x^{-1} = - \ln x$$

Exponentiate both sides:

$$e^{\ln x^{-1}} = e^{- \ln x}$$

Switch the sides to obtain as required.